# SAPUI5-How to create custom Split Page control

Tags: sapui5

I want to create a custom split -like page control.This page should contain two areas left and right content with different width.How to create this type of page as a custom control?

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Splitter: 
https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/Splitter.html

the relevant parameters for you are:

```
new sap.ui.commons.Splitter("splitterId", {
    splitterOrientation : sap.ui.commons.Orientation.Vertical, 
    splitterPosition : "50%",
    minSizeFirstPane : "0%",
    minSizeSecondPane : "0%",
    firstPaneContent : yourLeftContents, 
    secondPaneContent : yourRightContents
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But i want to create a new control itself extending page